# Not able to load background image in Reactjs, Webpack

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack

I'm trying to load background image in React project from custom css file. I am using Webpack 4.

```
.bgimage {
  height: 100vh;
  background: url('../images/header.jpg');
}
```

But my image is not shown and I have this error in console:

```
ERROR in ./src/app/assets/images/header.jpg
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected character '�' (1:0)
```

I have tried to add url-loader to my webpack.config.js

```
 {
   test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
   loader: "url-loader",
   query: { mimetype: "image/png" }
 }
```

But still image is not shown.

Comment: I guess a problem is in your webpack configuration. Something may be wrong with css-loader

Comment: try backgroundImage: "url(" ../images/header.jpg ")", also if you are using es6, import image first and add the value as backgroundImage: "url(" + Background + ")" - this will ensure image will be fetched on the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

I have found the solution that have worked for me. I have also installed `file-loader` and my background image was displayed.

File-loader installation:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-loader

Hope somebody will find it useful.